# How asp.net file upload to the server?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

how to upload my **asp.net** web site  on my own windows server?I searched the Internet but have not reached any conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has a publishing feature that allows you to deploy to the cloud, to a server or even just to the file system.

Read [How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx) for a tutorial on publishing.